# ioctl() gives different size each time

Tags: c, ipc, pipe

I am using ioctl() function call to get the size of data available on the pipe end and allocate the memory according to that.

For that I have written this code segment as

```
    if((read(mg_in, &byte, 1)) == 1)
            {
                    ioctl(mg_in, FIONREAD, &count);
                    buf = malloc(count+1);                                                          
                    buf[0] = byte;
                    read_count = read(mg_in, buf+1, count);

            }       
  buf_len = read_count+1;
```

From the another process, i always write the 4 bytes, but in the above code i get different value of the buf_len as 9, 5 etc though it should be buf_len=4 and read_count = 3.

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `ioctl` call succeeding?  Make sure it's returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `buf_len` regardless of whether your `read` succeeds and you set `count`. It's going to have junk in it if there's no data available to read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have tested the value of the read_count in the above code which means that read succeeds. But it reads 8 bytes while I write only 4 from the other end. But when i run the program for first time, it reads 4 but when i run the program next time it gives other values